# Getting started with MagicalRecord

Tags: core-data, xcode4.5, magicalrecord

I have an iPad app, using Storyboards, XCode 4.5 and iOS 6.  I am trying to get started using MagicalRecord.  I have everything installed and it builds correctly.  I have created an empty entity called ClientInfo with attributes.  I have also generated the NSManagedObject (Editor > Create NSManagedObject Subclass… > Create) but don't know what to do with it either.

This is the instruction that is my "brick wall"; I am unable to follow the following instruction:

> import the NSManagedObject subclass of the entity you want to save
>   into you’re class

I have looked at examples, Googled it and looked at SO.  I can't find a good example from starty to finish.  Anybody know of a real good doc or example on MagicalRecord?  Or, show me a real simple example that explains this where the MagicalRecord does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In Xcode, select the entities in the Core Data model editor and choose "Editor -> Create NSManagedObject Subclass ..." from the menu. This creates .h and .m for each entity, e.g. *ClientInfo.h* and *ClientInfo.m*.
2. Import the NSManagedObject subclass in your class file, e.g. `#import "ClientInfo.h"`.

Note that you have to redo step 1 after modifiying the entities.

The NSManagedObject subclasses declare all the properties and methods for you entity, so you can (for example) write

```
clientInfo.name = @"foo";
```

instead of

```
[clientInfo setValue:@"foo" forKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: Unbelievable!  I didn't even see the .h and .m files!  Thank you so much for showing me this.  I really, really appreciate it!